# How to extract a subset of a swift 3 Dictionary

Tags: swift, dictionary, swift3, nsdictionary

I've looked through the [methods here](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/dictionary) but I can't quite find what I'm looking for. I'm new-ish to Swift. I would like to extract a subset from a Dictionary based on a Set of key values, preferably without a loop.

For example, if my key Set is of type `Set<String>`  and I have a Dictionary of type `Dictionary<String, CustomObject>`, I would like to create a new Dictionary of type `Dictionary<String, CustomObject>` that contains only the key-value pairs associated with the keys in the Set of Strings.

I can see that I could do this with `for` loop, by initializing a new `Dictionary<String, CustomObj>()`, checking if the original Dictionary contains a value at each String in the set, and adding key-value pairs to the new Dictionary. I am wondering if there is a more efficient/elegant way to do this however.

I'd be open to finding the subset with an Array of Strings instead of a Set if there is a better way to do it with an Array of keys.

Many thanks!

Comment: @AntonBronnikov thanks, could you clarify - by "do that" you mean the iteration process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your assumption is correct, there is a more concise/swift-ish way to accomplish what you need.

For example you can do it via `reduce`, a functional programming concept available in Swift:

```
let subDict = originalDict.reduce([String: CustomObject]()) {
    guard mySet.contains($1.key) else { return $0 }
    var d = $0
    d[$1.key] = $1.value
    return d
}
```

Or, in two steps, first filtering the valid elements, and then constructing back the dictionary with the filtered elements:

```
let filteredDict = originalDict.filter { mySet.contains($0.key) }
    .reduce([CustomObject]()){ var d = $0; d[$1.key]=$1.value; return d }
```

`forEach` can also be used to construct the filtered dictionary:

```
var filteredDict = [CustomObject]()
mySet.forEach { filteredDict[$0] = originalDict[$0] }
```

, however the result would be good it it would be immutable:

```
let filteredDict: [String:CustomObject] = { 
    var result = [String:CustomObject]()
    mySet.forEach { filteredDict2[$0] = originalDict[$0] }
    return result
}()
```

Comment: That may look "swift-ish" but is very ineffective, because a new dictionary is created in each reducing step. Compare https://airspeedvelocity.net/2015/08/03/arrays-linked-lists-and-performance/.

Comment: @MartinR you're right, I have added some more solutions that shouldn't suffer from this problem. BTW, thanks for the article link, very insightful.

Comment: Perfect, just what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

**Swift 5** - You can do this very simply:

```
let subsetDict = originalDict.filter({ mySet.contains($0.key)})
```

The result is a new dictionary with the same type as the original but which only contains the key-value pairs corresponding to the keys in `mySet`.

Answer (score 0):

Dummy type:

```
struct CustomObject {
    let foo: Int
    init(_ foo: Int) { self.foo = foo }
}
```

In case you'd like to mutate the original dictionary (instead of creating a new one) in an "intersect" manner, based on a given set of keys:

```
let keySet = Set(["foo", "baz"])
var dict = ["foo": CustomObject(1), "bar": CustomObject(2),
            "baz": CustomObject(3), "bax": CustomObject(4)]

Set(dict.keys).subtracting(keySet).forEach { dict.removeValue(forKey: $0) }

print(dict) // ["foo": CustomObject(foo: 1), "baz": CustomObject(foo: 3)]
```